# Generic Priority Queue java implementation

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, priority-queue

I need to implement a Generic Priority Queue in JAVA. Note that both key and value is Generic. And all the data structures must be user implemented. The use of Java collections or any other data structures library is strictly forbidden. I used an Array to store data inside the Queue. But apparently generic array declaration is not possible. I can not use array list because then I will have to import libraries. 
And the code must be inside a single file. That class must implement a interface.
Interface:

```
    public interface PQK<P extends Comparable<P>, T> {

    // Return the length of the queue
    int length();

    // Enqueue a new element. The queue keeps the k elements with the highest priority. In case of a tie apply FIFO.
    void enqueue(P pr, T e);

    // Serve the element with the highest priority. In case of a tie apply FIFO.
    Pair<P, T> serve();
}
```

Class I wrote for the priority queue implementing the given interface:

```
public class PQKImp<P extends Comparable<P>, T> implements PQK<P, T> {

    private int size;
    private int capacity;
    private Pair<P , T>[] heap;

    public PQKImp(int k) {
        heap = new Pair<P,T>[k];
        this.capacity = k;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public int length(){
        return size;
    }

    public void enqueue(P pr, T e){
        Pair<P ,T> pair = new Pair<P,T>(pr , e);
        heap[++size] = pair;
        int pos = size;
        while(pos!=1 && pair.first.compareTo(heap[pos/2].first)<0){
            heap[pos] = heap[pos/2];
            pos /= 2;
        }
        heap[pos] = pair;
    }

    public Pair<P,T> serve(){
        return heap[0];
    }
}
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
.\PQKImp.java:8: error: generic array creation
                heap = new Pair<P,T>[k];
                       ^
1 error
```

Can you please suggest me an possible method to store data in my class.
Thank you

Comment: instead of `new Pair<P,T>[k];`, use `new Pair[k];`

Comment: wow that just worked. You saved my life Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
    String name;
    int rollNumber;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    public void setRollNumber(int rollNumber) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", rollNumber=" + rollNumber + "]";
    }

    public Employee(String name, int rollNumber) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee o) {
        return rollNumber - o.getRollNumber();
    }

}

public class PriorityQueueImplementation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Employee> employees = new PriorityQueue<>();

        Employee e1 = new Employee("A", 1);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("B", 3);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("C", 2);
        Employee e4 = new Employee("D", 5);
        Employee e5 = new Employee("E", 6);
        Employee e6 = new Employee("F", 8);
        Employee e7 = new Employee("G", 10);
        Employee e8 = new Employee("H", 4);
        Employee e9 = new Employee("I", 7);
        Employee e10 = new Employee("J", 9);

        employees.add(e1);
        employees.add(e2);
        employees.add(e3);
        employees.add(e4);
        employees.add(e5);
        employees.add(e6);
        employees.add(e7);
        employees.add(e8);
        employees.add(e9);
        employees.add(e10);
        
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            System.out.println(employee);
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Print By Priority Queue");
        while(!employees.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(employees.remove());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The Employee class is a simple model class which is implementing the Comparable interface because for the priority queue we need to implement the generic class from comparable